# Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to infinity. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded from below.

Tags: real-analysis

I do not know how to start this proof.

I know that for a sequence to be bounded below that there is some number K such that $x_n \geq K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I also know that the sequence converges to infinity provided that for every $M >0$ there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow x_n > M$.

I am unsure how to use these two theorems to prove the sequence is bounded from below.

Comment: Hint: How many $x_n$ can be below a given $M$?

Comment: Please make the body of your question self-contained. The title is not part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using the two things you said you knew in your post, you can supply a number $K$ that is a lower bound for $\{x_n\}$ like this:

Take $N$ so that if $n\ge N$, $x_n \ge 100$.

We would be done with $K = 100$ if $x_n \ge 100$ for all $n$, but we only know $x_n \ge 100$ for $n\ge N$. So only $x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}$ could possibly be $< 100$.

Maybe even all of $x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}$ happen to actually be $\ge 100$, and then we are done with $K = 100$. However, it could transpire that some (or all) of $x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}$ are $< 100$. Fortunately, this is a finite list of numbers, so if we define $K = \min(x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}, 100)$, then $x_1,\dots, x_{N-1} \ge K$ (by definition), and $x_n \ge 100 \ge K$ for $n \ge  N$, so we have a lower bound $K$ which is not explicit, but is defined in terms of the sequence itself.

This kind of thing is pretty typical of many situations in analysis, where you have a good understanding of some "large" part of your problem, and "the rest" of the problem is hopefully smaller than the "large" part, and therefore ideally easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$

is $\forall M > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, x_n > M$.

So take, in particular, $M = 1$. Then take some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N, x_n > M$. Define $K = \inf(\{M\} \cup \{x_i | i < N\})$. This is valid because every finite non-empty set has an infinum.

Then $x \leq x_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Close, but you've missed something like "${} \to \infty$" in the second line of your answer. $M =1 $ would be a better choice than $M = 0$ and you don't need to mess around with infima.

Comment: @RobArthan Good catch on the $= \infty$ part. However, I'm not sure why $M = 1$ is any better or worse than $M = 0$.

Comment: If you take $M = 0$, then $M > 0$ isn't true, so when you write "take in particular ..." something is wrong.

Comment: @RobArthan Good point. I have changed it.